# How to avoid repeat the same satellite information in list?

Tags: android, gps, satellite

I create a simple application for shows GPS sensor satellite informations.
Informations shows as text and list never stop to updated with same repeat informations.
How i keep the unique sattelites infos?Not repeat the same infos.

```
public void onGpsStatusChanged() {

  GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
  if(gpsStatus != null) {
      Iterable<GpsSatellite>satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
      Iterator<GpsSatellite>sat = satellites.iterator();
      int i=0;
      while (sat.hasNext()) {
          GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();
           strGpsStats+= (i++) + ": " + "Pseudo-random number for the satellite:  "+satellite.getPrn() + "," + "Satellite was used by the GPS calculation: " + satellite.usedInFix() + "," + "Signal to noise ratio for the satellite: "+satellite.getSnr() + "," + "Azimuth of the satellite in degrees: "+satellite.getAzimuth() + "," +"Elevation of the satellite in degrees: "+satellite.getElevation()+ "\n\n";
      }

      Satinfos.setText(strGpsStats);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're not clearing your `strGpsStats` between each call to the `onGpsStatusChanged`; although not sure because your question is not very clear. Try this:

```
public void onGpsStatusChanged() {
  strGpsStats = "";
  GpsStatus gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);
  if(gpsStatus != null) {
      Iterable<GpsSatellite>satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites();
      Iterator<GpsSatellite>sat = satellites.iterator();
      int i=0;
      while (sat.hasNext()) {
          GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();
           strGpsStats+= (i++) + ": " + "Pseudo-random number for the satellite:  "+satellite.getPrn() + "," + "Satellite was used by the GPS calculation: " + satellite.usedInFix() + "," + "Signal to noise ratio for the satellite: "+satellite.getSnr() + "," + "Azimuth of the satellite in degrees: "+satellite.getAzimuth() + "," +"Elevation of the satellite in degrees: "+satellite.getElevation()+ "\n\n";
      }

      Satinfos.setText(strGpsStats);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After Entering into the while, need to check for repeated info.

```
    while (sat.hasNext()) {
          GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();
            if(sat.Current != sat.next)
{
           strGpsStats+= (i++) + ": " + "Pseudo-random number for the satellite:  "+satellite.getPrn() + "," + "Satellite was used by the GPS calculation: " + satellite.usedInFix() + "," + "Signal to noise ratio for the satellite: "+satellite.getSnr() + "," + "Azimuth of the satellite in degrees: "+satellite.getAzimuth() + "," +"Elevation of the satellite in degrees: "+satellite.getElevation()+ "\n\n";
      }
}
```

Comment: Maybe needs Array? if data(i++)!=data(i)